# Modify an SQL query to include additional parameters

Tags: sql, parameters, extract

I would like to extract data via an SQL query, but the given code does not give me a report, which would include all the data I'd like to have.

Basically, the report combines data from many samples (95 to be exact) and then gives me sequences from these samples. It also compares these sequences to see, whether they pop up in more sample than 1.

I would like to include the parameters "v_family" and "j_gene" as additional columns and the query needs to get these from one of the samples (in a similar way as it gets the amino acid sequence ("amino_acid") from one of the samples, where this sequence appears).

How do I get my two additional parameters into this report?

This is the current query resulting in 6 columns (also see attached screenshot):

```
select 
    value, 
    rank, 
    count(*) over (partition by amino_acid) as contributors, 
    total, 
    amino_acid, 
    sample_name 
from ( select 
        value, 
        row_number() over (partition by sample_name order by rank desc) as rank, 
        sum(value) over (partition by amino_acid) as total, 
        amino_acid, 
        sample_name 
            from ( select 
                        sum(productive_frequency) as value, 
                        sum(productive_frequency) as rank, 
                        amino_acid, 
                        sample_name 
                    from sequences 
                    group by 
                        amino_acid, 
                        sample_name 
                    order by 
                        value desc 
            )inner_query  
    ) outer_inner  
order by 
    sample_name asc, 
    rank
```

The following edit was proposed, but did not result in the data I wanted (see attached screenshots):

```
select value, rank, count(*) over (partition by amino_acid) as contributors, total, amino_acid, sample_name from ( select value, row_number() over (partition by sample_name order by rank desc) as rank, sum(value) over (partition by amino_acid) as total, amino_acid, sample_name from ( select sum(productive_frequency) as value, sum(productive_frequency) as rank, amino_acid, sample_name, v_family from sequences group by amino_acid, sample_name, v_family order by value desc ) inner_query  ) outer_inner  order by sample_name asc, rank
```

[old query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHPk7.png)

[new query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PI10.png)

This was suggested, but did not change the outcome:

```
select 
    value, 
    rank, 
    total, 
    amino_acid, 
    sample_name 
from ( select 
        value, 
        row_number() over (partition by sample_name order by rank desc) as rank, 
        sum(value) over (partition by amino_acid) as total, count(*) over (partition by amino_acid,v_family,j_gene) as contributors,
        amino_acid, 
       sample_name from ( SELECT sum(productive_frequency) AS value
    ,sum(productive_frequency) AS rank
    ,v_family
    ,j_gene
    ,amino_acid
    ,sample_name
FROM sequences
GROUP BY amino_acid
    ,sample_name
    ,v_family
    ,j_gene
ORDER BY value DESC ) inner_query ) outer_inner order by sample_name asc, rank
```

OK it was solved! The correct code is the following, Thanks so much for everyone, who helped!

```
SELECT value
    ,rank
    ,count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY amino_acid,v_family,j_gene) AS contributors
    ,total
    ,amino_acid
    ,sample_name
    ,v_family
    ,j_gene
FROM (
    SELECT value
        ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY sample_name ORDER BY rank DESC) AS rank
        ,sum(value) OVER (PARTITION BY amino_acid,v_family,j_gene) AS total
        ,amino_acid
        ,sample_name
        ,v_family
        ,j_gene
    FROM (
        SELECT sum(productive_frequency) AS value
            ,sum(productive_frequency) AS rank
            ,v_family
            ,j_gene
            ,amino_acid
            ,sample_name
        FROM sequences
        GROUP BY amino_acid
            ,sample_name
            ,v_family
            ,j_gene
        ORDER BY value DESC
        ) inner_query
    ) outer_inner
ORDER BY sample_name ASC
    ,rank
```

Comment: Please, format your query so it becomes readable. (When you edit, mark the code, click `{}`. Add line-breaks and adjust indentation.)

Comment: What version of SQL are you on (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc)? Also, what are you using to extract the data?

Comment: I'm not sure which SQL version this is, unfortunately. I use the company's web access to input the query and extract the data, but it does not give any other information. I'm very sorry about that, I know it's important to have that info.

Comment: Maybe this helps, it says in the description: 

"The Advanced Query view provides a rich SQL-style interface to immunoSEQ sample and rearrangement details.

This view will only be useful to you if you are comfortable with database concepts. You can use most common SQL operators to select values from the virtual tables samples and sequences. These virtual tables are constructed using the samples from the active project and the filters you've defined on the current analysis."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It might the effect of adding 2 new columns to base query. The "group by" statement does group data by unique combination of selected columns that in both cases are different.
Compare these queries results:

`SELECT sum(productive_frequency) AS value
    ,sum(productive_frequency) AS rank
    ,v_family
    ,j_gene
    ,amino_acid
    ,sample_name
FROM sequences
GROUP BY amino_acid
    ,sample_name
    ,v_family
    ,j_gene
ORDER BY value DESC`

and

    `SELECT sum(productive_frequency) AS value
    ,sum(productive_frequency) AS rank
    ,amino_acid
    ,sample_name
FROM sequences
GROUP BY amino_acid
    ,sample_name
ORDER BY value DESC`

If the rows count is different then u can check for unique combination of mentioned columns using following statement :

`select distinct
    v_family
    ,j_gene
    ,amino_acid
    ,sample_name
FROM sequences`

While the inner_query result changed, change window function from

`sum(value) over (partition by amino_acid) as total,`

to

`sum(value) over (partition by amino_acid,v_family,j_gene) as total,` 

And sorry for replies that were adding each time i pressed [Enter]

New version.

`SELECT value
    ,rank
    ,count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY amino_acid,v_family,j_gene) AS contributors
    ,total
    ,amino_acid
    ,sample_name
    ,v_family
    ,j_gene
FROM (
    SELECT value
        ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY sample_name ORDER BY rank DESC) AS rank
        ,sum(value) OVER (PARTITION BY amino_acid,v_family,j_gene) AS total
        ,amino_acid
        ,sample_name
        ,v_family
        ,j_gene
    FROM (
        SELECT sum(productive_frequency) AS value
            ,sum(productive_frequency) AS rank
            ,v_family
            ,j_gene
            ,amino_acid
            ,sample_name
        FROM sequences
        GROUP BY amino_acid
            ,sample_name
            ,v_family
            ,j_gene
        ORDER BY value DESC
        ) inner_query
    ) outer_inner
ORDER BY sample_name ASC
    ,rank`

Comment: Unfortunatly, your first command results in the "wrong" contributors column with numbers up to 20 (just like Girish's did) and the second one results in the original output, again without the columns I need. 

I also tried the "select distinct" added to the first query, but this did not change the outcome of the data query.

Comment: Try changing line :

Comment: Change
<code>sum(value) over (partition by amino_acid) as total,</code>
to
</code>sum(value) over (partition by amino_acid,v_family,j_gene) as total,</code>

Comment: Ah im sorry for those - im new here. I did updated my answer.

Comment: I put this line into your first and second query. 

It resulted in data output when added to the first one, but the column "contributors" vanished and the columns I want are not there. 

It did not result in data, when added to your second query.

Comment: I tried to change what you said (I took your first query and then edited the "sum(value) over (partition by amino_acid,v_family,j_gene) as total", but it still results in the wrong values in "contributors" and not in additional columns...

Comment: <code>count(*) over (partition by amino_acid,v_family,j_gene) as contributors,</code>
maybe this wil help.

Comment: Please look at my original question, I put there what I used for the query now (after your comments), but it did not work yet, unfortunatly...

Comment: Updated my answer. Check upper.

Comment: It works for two samples! I'll have to check if it works for 95, but I don't see a reason why it shouldn't ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your multi level query is all based on inner most query where data is selected from table/view "sequence", so if 2 more parameters are needed,  it will have to be added in inner most query only, with most likely one or more additional table which will be joined to "sequence" table/view.

Instead of current 4 columns value, rank, amino_acids, sample_name than there will be 6 columns ( plus Gene, Family ) in inner most query. These additional 2 columns will have to be included in group by, and so they will be appearing in top most query.

Comment: To test this I included the parameter "v_family" into the inner query and the group by, but this simply changed the column "contributors" to display strange numbers (aka up to 20, when I only selected 2 samples in this analysis and the highest number could, therefore, be "2"). I still only have 6 columns.

... sample_name from ( select sum(productive_frequency) as value, sum(productive_frequency) as rank, amino_acid, sample_name, v_family from sequences group by amino_acid, sample_name, v_family order by value desc ) inner_query  ) outer_inner  order by sample_name asc, rank

Comment: You can compare the results of both queries using below query, sum should be same. If it is not, need to debug further mainly all partition functions inside 

`select sum( contributors ) from (  old query with 4 columns  )  `

and

` select sum( contributors ) from (  new query with 6 columns  )  `

Comment: I pasted the screenshots in my original question, the only thing changing was the "contributors" column, which now showed impossible numbers (as the example only includes 2 samples, only 1 or 2 are possible outcomes here).

Comment: what is the reason you kept `count(*) over (partition by amino_acid) as contributors` at outer query, It should be working in inner most query or inner query.. and value can be carried outside they way rank and values are moved..

Comment: I tried moving the "count(*) over  (partition by amino_acid) as contributors" to the inner query or to the innermost query, but in both cases, the column "contributors" simply vanished.

Comment: If you move it inside, than in the next upper level you will have to include it in select, thats how it will be there until last query

Comment: I moved it into the innermost, then added it to the next upper level and deleted it from the outside, but this still eliminates my "contributors" column and does not add a "v_family" column.

Comment: Can you please share screen shot of all inner queries, 1st screen should be inner most query, 2nd next upper level and so on..